# Formulário com upload para imagem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

Como faço para fazer upload de imagens em ASP.Net MVC? Tenho um formulário de cadastro onde o usuário tem a opção de enviar uma imagem para utilizar em seu perfil. Um exemplo seria útil.

Comment: Favoritei. Mais tarde coloco o código completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VIEW]

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create",
                        "Arquivo",
                        FormMethod.Post,
                        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
}
```

[CONTROLLER]

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collecion, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Erro", "Nenhum arquivo selecionado.");
            return View();
        }
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Arquivos/" + file.FileName));
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
```

Comment: Obrigado! Consigo ver o nome da imagem no banco de dados, porém gostaria de exibir a imagem no lugar do nome. Você saberia como fazer?